# Listening to keyboard events in MFC within PreTranslateMessage()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I was trying to use the following code to listen to simple keyboard events in a dialog based application, but nothing is happening on pressing these keys. Can somebody tell me what went wrong ?

```
BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG *pMsg)
{

CListeningApp* App = (CListeningApp*) AfxGetApp();
int x=(int)pMsg->wParam;

if(pMsg->message==WM_KEYDOWN)
{
    if(x==VK_UP)
    MessageBox(NULL,L"UP",L"UP", MB_OK);

    if(x==VK_DOWN)
    MessageBox(NULL,L"DOWN",L"DOWN", MB_OK);

    if(x==VK_RIGHT)
    MessageBox(NULL,L"RIGHT",L"RIGHT", MB_OK);

    if(x==VK_LEFT)
    MessageBox(NULL,L"LEFT",L"LEFT", MB_OK);

    if(x==65)
        MessageBox(NULL,L"Keyboard Event",L"You Pressed the letter a", MB_OK);


}
return TRUE;

}
```

Comment: Because nobody calls `PreTranslateMessage`. Your `PreTranslateMessage` is just a standalone function. You could rename your `PreTranslateMessage` to `foobar`, the result would be the same. Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kkbhxcs2.aspx).

Comment: Just a suggestion: never ever debug anything with the `MessageBox()`, especially not the keyboard event handler. Use `::OutputDebugString()` and watch for it in the debugger's Output window.

Comment: @VladFeinstein it works here for testing purposes, but you are right `OutputDebugString` is better.

Comment: Handling key messages is a lot of work if you have many controls in dialog box --- If this is related to your earlier question, make sure the Scroll bar control has `WS_TABSTOP` flag (look for "Tab" flag in dialog editor), overload dialog's `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` to set focus to the desired control --- or use Slider control instead

Comment: @BarmakShemirani this one is not related to my previous query, its a blank dialog-based app with no components, so can you give me a suggestion in that perspective ?

Comment: You are on the right track then. See Michael Walz's answer, make sure you call the base class: `return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);` otherwise it crashes. Only if you process the message, then `TRUE` to indicate that you have handled the message yourself.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani it is crashing in both the return cases..

Comment: @BarmakShemirani it is giving me a LNK2001 unresolved extrnal symbol error

Comment: The link error is from something else. Read the full link error properly, it should say what it is. Rebuild the project if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `PreTranslateMessage` function is a stand alone function. It won't be called automatically just because it's name is `PreTranslateMessage`.

The function must be member of your dialog class.

```
BOOL CYourDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
...
}
```

`CYourDlg` being the *your* dialog class.

And somewhere in the declaration of your dialog class `CYourDlg` put:

```
virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg);
```

Comment: True enough. You just forgot to mention that there is little point in doing this in `PreTranslateMessage`. Rather, simply override `OnKeyDown`.

Comment: Also call the base class `return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);`